# Performance counter duration with C#

Tags: c#, performancecounter

I am looking to use performance counters to track the number of objects that are processed throughout the day using a C# application. From my research, I found PerformanceCounterType.NumberOfItems32 to be the most appropriate to use.

My question is, how long does a performance counter last (the data in it, not the counter itself)? If a performance counter is created during an initial setup routine and incremented throughout the day, do I need to reset it at midnight?

Comment: Whatever apps reads it needs to decide between data loss if it starts too late or an inaccurate value if it starts too soon.  Why don't you just log the count somewhere?  EventLog, dbase, something like that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The data in the counter will last until the object is disposed, at which point the data is lost. If you are interested in obtaining values on a per-day basis, this means that you would have to reset the value over night somehow.

However, I personally use [ANTS Performance Profiler](http://www.red-gate.com/products/dotnet-development/ants-performance-profiler/) to obtain this kind of information from my programs. It provides insight in how often objects are used, how often functions are called, how long it takes to process them, etc. It's not inexpensive, but it may be worth looking into if you would like detailed insight in a fairly simple manner.